# Will broadcast variables work in Spark in this case?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, broadcast

I am using broadcast variable to send some info to all the worker nodes in spark.
The data is in JSONObject format.

Here is the logic of how my application works -

1. Read the JSONObject data
2. Convert it into a string
3. Create a Broadcast variable of type String and store the data of step 2.
4. Now, the broadcast variable should be availale to all the worker nodes.
5. Then, I take out the string from the broadcast variable.
6. Then, I convert the string back to a JSONObject.
7. Finally, I continue to use this JSONObject as every worker node will have access to it.

So, is this the right way to share data across all the nodes, if I am using broadcast variables ?

Comment: It should be possible but you can create a sample code and try it out in local mode. You can add the code you are trying here too so if there is any issue it can be sorted

Comment: @VindhyaG yeah, I created a sample code and ran it on a cluster mode. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I created a sample code using the steps above and ran it on a cluster. It worked because strings are serializable by default.